# How can I make a single commit of specific branch from other pushed commits in Git?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-commit

I am new to Git.

I have one main branch "development" in which all branches will be merged 
and I'm working on branch "`TESST123`"

I have done three commits (using : `git commit -am "comment"`) and pushed (using : `git push origin TESST123`) one by one, e.g.

```
Commit 07834343kfjsd948343243....
Author myname
date thu aug 14 17:20:37 2014

Commit 34sdsad32432432dfdsf....
Author myname
date thu aug 14 15:12:52 2014

Commit dfasdsadkfjsd948343243....
Author myname
date thu aug 14 00:08:06 2014
```

---

How can I merge all those commits in a single commit in branch `TESST123` and then again push so the resulting branch will be with one commit containing all applied changes..

I have searched for squash but didn't understand it clearly.

If possible, try to answer with `git` command.

Comment: You accepted an answer; that's good. But don't hesitate to also upvote answers that you find useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in your local repo, using [`git merge-base`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base):

```
git checkout TESST123
git reset --soft `git merge-base TESST123 dev`
git commit -m 'All of TESST123'
```

You would need to force push your branch though, as its history has changed. That can be an issue only if others have cloned your remote repo and worked from that same branch.

```
git push --force origin TESST123
```

You can also merge locally that one commit into `dev`:

```
git checkout dev
git merge TESST123
```

Answer (score 0):

found another way to git rebase -i HEAD~3

pick dfasdsad

pick 34sdsad3

pick 07834343

appliying squash to merge 34sdsad3 , 0783434 into dfasdsad

pick dfasdsad

squash 34sdsad3

squash 07834343

will merge last two commits into single commit